# ant calling rake

Tags: ant, rake

I think I'm having issues with my ant not knowing where to find my Rakefile

I have the following folder structure.

```
build.xml    
[subfolder]/Rakefile
```

Within my build.xml I have the following task.

```
 <target name="client">
    <taskdef name="rake" classname="org.jruby.ant.Rake" classpath="../shared-lib/jruby.jar"/>
   <rake task="jar"/>
  </target>
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
build.xml: Could not create type rake due to org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: no such file to load -- ant/tasks/raketasks
```

Any help apprec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a comprehensive article about the combination (both ant from rake and rake from ant):

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rake-and-ant-together-a-pick-it-n-stick-it-approach/

Do make sure of the following:

- the Rake task classpath includes any dependencies that JRuby has
- the Rakefile is in root directory (i.e. `basedir`)

By default when you execute the Rake command from the command line it looks in the *current* directory for the Rakefile.  If your root Rakefile does nothing other than change directories and call the other Rakefile it should be better.

Comment: I've created a build.xml in the same dir as my Rakefile but still running into the same problems.

Comment: Ok so you put me on the right path. I was using a standard jruby.jar but I needed the the jruby-complete.jar In addition for some reason I needed to set this jar to be in ants command line CLASSPATH. After all that my Rakefile would run.